# Rails multiple record update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following array of boolean attributes for multiple records

```
{"utf8"=>"✓","_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "ts"=>
  {"1"=>{"go"=>"0", "pickup"=>"0", "delivery"=>"1"},
   "2"=>{"go"=>"0", "pickup"=>"0", "delivery"=>"1"},
   "3"=>{"go"=>"0", "pickup"=>"0", "delivery"=>"1"},
   [...]},
 "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

is being posted from one controller to a child controller with the following action that has un-conventional naming for the parameters.

```
   def update_all
      params[:ts].keys.each do |id|
        @daystruttimeslot = Daystruttimeslot.find(id.to_i)
        @daystruttimeslot.update(ts_params)
      end
    end
```

is hitting the error `undefined local variable or method 'ts_params' for #<DaystruttimeslotsController:0x00007fa118f262f8> Did you mean? to_param params @_params`

How can these parameters be properly processed by this action?

Comment: Is `ts_params` defined somewhere?

Comment: no, it is not.  how could they be invoked? (I thought rails was getting it from the call `"ts"=>`

Comment: I don't understand your question. You try to use local variable or method `ts_params`, did you define it anywhere?

Comment: Invoked, just by calling them. Try something like `params['ts'].each { |id, values| Daystruttimeslot.find_by!(id: id).update(values) }`, you're getting each Daystruttimeslot id and their values to update the record, you must be iterating over each key and values from that hash.

Comment: Rails does not automatically define params whitelisting methods. I don't know where you got that notion from.

Answer (score 1):

```
def update_all
  ts = params.require(:ts)
  @daystruttimeslots = Daystruttimeslot.where(id: ts.keys)
  @daystruttimeslots.each do |d|
    d.update(ts.fetch(d.id.to_s).permit(:go, :pickup, :delivery))
  end
end
```

This does a single read operation instead of fetching each record separately and also provides a ivar that actually makes sense instead of whatever is at the end of the loop.

If you need to validate that all the ids are correct compare `ts.keys.length` to `@daystruttimeslots.size`. You also might want to consider wrapping this in a transaction so that the changes are rolled back if any of the updates fail instead of just leaving the job half done.